# External environment config not working in Spring Boot dependency library

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, dependencies

I have a spring boot application (microservice), say SB1, one of whose rest API is calling a custom spring boot application, say SBA, that I have created for some common features. Eventually I want other spring boot microservices like SB1, SB2, SB3...etc to call this common SBA.

Now this SBA is a jar (SBA-common-utils) that I have injected as a dependency in SB1 like this:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abc.micro</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-utils</artifactId>
    <version>${SBA-common-utils.version}</version>
</dependency>
...
```

SBA doesn't have a main class and is used as helper for common features across all microservices.

Now here is the real **problem**, when I am trying to externalize configuration in SBA for different environments. The configuration that I define in application.properties in **SBA/src/main/resources**, is not getting picked up and I get it as **NULL** when I try to fetch its value in one of the service classes defined in **SBA/src/main/java.../package/abc.java**.

```
@Value("${spring.config.name}")
```

The SB1 on the other hand can fetch the application configuration from its respective **SB1/src/resources** files.

Is SBA not loading the configuration as its not being started as a @SpringBootApplication? If not, what options can I try to see what the issue could be?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at that : https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Comment: That's a different approach all together. Is there any solution to the above?